# macos grant access to system keychain for app

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

Is there any way to grant read access to one specify certificate or private key for one particular app via script and/or terminal in MacOS (High sirra and/or Mojave).

I can do it via the graphical interface. But I want to archive this via terminal and/or script.

KeyChain - > System - > Keys -> Double Click Private key XY - > Access Control - > Confirm Before Allowing - > Add App XY - Save Changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `security` command during the import/install of the certificate. If certificate is already installed, you can either use GUI as you have mentioned or delete the private key and reinstall it using below command.

`sudo security import <path_to_cert_or_private_key_file> -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain  -P <password_of_the_certificate_file>  -T <path_to_the_app>`